# Garbage Collector not Disposing of Excel-Instance in the same Method

Tags: c#, excel, garbage-collection, excel-interop

I have a Program which uses Excel-Interop. Now, if i call the Application.Quit-Method, it does not close the Excel Process, the Garbage-Collector has to run first. But for some reason, the Garbage Collector only works properly if it is called in a different Method than the one which uses Excel.

Why is that?

```
        public static void MethodA()
        {
            MethodB();
            //Calling the Garbage-Collector here DOES close the Excel-Process
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        public static void MethodB()
        {
            Application ExcelApp = new Application();

            ExcelApp.Quit();
            ExcelApp = null;

            //Calling the Garbage-Collector here DOES NOT close the Excel-Process
            //GC.Collect();
            //GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector only reclaims unused memory. The Finalizer may be used to reclaim other kinds of resources. However, the finalizer is non-deterministic, and may potentially never run. Therefore I would argue that well designed programs should always use the IDisposable interface to reclaim any native resource, and only use the finalizer as a fallback. In short, you should (ideally) never have to call Gc.Collect or Gc.WaitForPendingFinalizer.

Since "Application" does not implement IDisposable, but apparently has a finalizer, it seems like the object is not well-designed.

The garbage collector is allowed to reclaim objects any time after the last usage. But this might depend on if you are running in debug or release, and if you have a debugger attached or not. It is possible that the compiler extends the lifetime to make debugging easier. So as Far as I know both examples should work the same, and if does not, it is probably some complicated, undocumented behavior that should not be relied on.